# Breaking txt file into list of lists by character and by row

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, file-read

I am just learning to code and am trying to take an input txt file and break into a list (by row) where each row's characters are elements of that list.  For example if the file is:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

I would like to create

```
[['a','b','c','d','e'], ['f','g','h','i','j'],['k','l','m','n','o']]
```

I have tried this, but the results aren't what I am looking for.

```
file = open('alpha.txt', 'r')
lst = []
for line in file:
    lst.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
print(lst)
[['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno']]
```

I also tried this, which is closer, but I don't know how to combine the two codes:

```
file = open('alpha.txt', 'r')
lst = []
for line in file:
    for c in line:
        lst.append(c)
print(lst)
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
```

I tried to add the `rstrip` into the `lst.append` but it didn't work (or I didn't do it properly).  Sorry - complete newbie here!

I should mention that I don't want newline characters included.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you all, this is a big help.  I haven't learned 'with open' yet, and Dekel's response seems most in keeping with how I am trying to learn.  MUCH APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split a string to it's charts you can just use `list(s)` (where `s = 'asdf'`):

```
file = open('alpha.txt', 'r')
lst = []
for line in file:
    lst.append(list(line.strip()))

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. You have to use the `list()` constructor to make a string into its respective characters.

```
with open('alpha.txt', 'r') as file:
    print([list(line)[:-1] for line in file.readlines()])
```

(The `with open` construct is just an idiom, so you don't have to do all the handling with the file like closing it, which you forgot to do)

Answer (score 0):

You are appending each entry to your original list. You want to create a new list for each line in your input, append to that list, and then append that list to your master list. For example,

```
file = open('alpha.txt', 'r')
lst = []
for line in file:
    newLst = []
    for c in line:
        newLst.append(c)
    lst.append(newLst)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a nested list comprehension. The outer loop iterates over the lines in the file and the inner loop over the characters in the strings of each line.

```
with open('alpha.txt') as f:
    out = [[char for char in line.strip()] for line in f]

req = [['a','b','c','d','e'], ['f','g','h','i','j'],['k','l','m','n','o']]

print(out == req)
```

prints

> True